# How can I be sure that calls to native code are made on the same OS thread?

Tags: c#, .net

From C# code, I am calling a native library that requires callers to follow certain threading rules. The interface to the library is, in essence as follows:

```
void* CreateModel();
void DoStuff(const void* model);
void DestroyModel(const void* model);
```

The `CreateModel()` function instantiates a new model which is returned as a void pointer. The other functions provide functionality that act on that model.

The threading rule that clients must follow is that all calls that accept a model are made from the same OS thread that made the call to `CreateModel()`. The library is threadsafe in that multiple threads can operate on different model instances. But each model has affinity to the OS thread on which it was created.

My question, is whether or not I need to do anything special to ensure that I adhere to these threading rules. I understand that managed threads are not necessarily mapped onto the same OS thread for the entire lifetime of the managed thread.

I read the following from the MSDN topic [Managed and Unmanaged Threading in Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74169f59.aspx):

> An operating-system **ThreadId** has no fixed relationship to a managed thread, because an unmanaged host can control the relationship between managed and unmanaged threads. Specifically, a sophisticated host can use the Fiber API to schedule many managed threads against the same operating system thread, or to move a managed thread among different operating system threads.

How do I interpret this? My C# application certainly does not move managed threads between different OS threads. In that case, am I safe to assume that nothing else does?

Comment: Thank you @Hans, that's just what I was looking for. All I could find was lots of dire warnings that the framework would schedule managed threads onto different OS threads.