# How do you check if a calling thread has thread affinity turned on?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winapi, affinity

If I were to build a library, I might have a static function that does a `Thread.BeginThreadAffinity()` at the start of the function and `Thread.EndThreadAffinity()` at the end, or in the finalizer, of the function because I want to enforce a 1-to-1 mapping of managed to OS (native) threads:

```
public static void DoSomething()
{
    Thread.BeginThreadAffinity()
    // Do something, like a few P/Invokes that would require me to have thread affinity.
    Thread.EndThreadAffinity()
}
```

The issue is this: If the caller already has thread affinity on their thread before calling `DoSomething()`, I might want to check that thread affinity is already on the current thread, so that in the finalizer of my function, I don't end thread affinity for the caller. So, is there any way to check if the calling thread has enabled affinity? If not, I might have to spawn a new thread for each call to this static function and wait on an AutoResetEvent.

Comment: This is pointless, no common CLR host exists that makes this necessary.

Comment: @HansPassant Then why does Thread.BeginThreadAffinity() exist?

Comment: They could not predict that the feature wasn't ever going to be used.  The SQL Server project that asked for it and intended to use fibers was a failure, that was the end of it.

Comment: @HansPassant So then why did they keep it around? If they kept it around in case they ever try it again, I can't predict that it won't be used in the future of .NET, so I want to ensure my code is as robust as possible in the future. Plus, if you're basing your answer from this MSDN article (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.beginthreadaffinity.aspx) it states that: *"Some hosts of the common language runtime, such as Microsoft SQL Server 2005, provide their own thread management."* This does not imply that's the only project that ever asked for it.

Comment: Because they of course cannot remove a feature that *somebody* might have used.  The odds that you'll ever run into that somebody are zero, +/- 1%.  You probably completely overlooked the requirement to write your own custom CLR host so you could test.  Adding code that's unnecessary never makes software more robust.  It merely adds untestable code that's guarantee to fail when it is actually needed because it was never tested.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't agree with your argument on the simple basis that untested code is **not** guaranteed to fail. In this case, I don't see how Thread.BeginThreadAffinity() or Thread.EndThreadAffinity() could fail in the future if the CLR host supports it, unless the underlying CLR host code is broken. Also, what about my point that this article clearly states, which is that *some* CLR hosts exhibit this behavior? I don't interpret the word *some* as *one*...because it doesn't say that just the SQL Server 2005 project ever did or does this...so where are you basing your answer from?

Comment: I've been answering CLR hosting questions for 8 years, never handled one that asked about ICLRTaskManager.  If I would have, I would have pointed out how useless that is on modern machines with multi-core processors.  It isn't exactly my concern to find a CLR host that implements it.  It is yours.  Good luck finding one.

Comment: @HansPassant My point is this...how do you know that CLR hosting in .NET, other than in Microsoft SQL Server 2005, doesn't enforce this sort of behavior? If you don't know, then maybe you shouldn't say its pointless to try to enforce thread affinity. If you do know, I'd like to see some proof!

Comment: I agree with Hans. You are being paranoid. Which is probably my fault. I started you on this path. I'm convinced: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20105217/how-can-i-be-sure-that-calls-to-native-code-are-made-on-the-same-os-thread

Comment: Paranoia is an awesome learning tool. Yours in particular has taught me a lot over the last few days. Many Stack users have more points and more experience than me, but that doesn't mean I shouldn't challenge their arguments to get to, what I feel is, a correct and concise answer.

Comment: At this point, I feel like ignoring thread affinity is a horrible assumption to make; you're telling me to assume it won't happen, which is fine if you could prove that it truly won't, and guarantee it won't in the future as well...but even if it could happen 0.01% of the time, that's enough of a percentage to want me to ensure that I handle it *all* the time.

Comment: Plus, I can't believe you're so quick to brush it off after the big deal you made about it.